# Compare standard deviations in different samples?

Tags: outlier, sampling, mean

I have some data which you can group based on different variables.

I know how to test if they have significantly different means. But what the deviation inside the samples?

Comment: please provide more information on what you mean by "test" and why different variances make this difficult

Comment: I can look at two samples and see which has higher variance, but is there a test that can confirm whether this difference is significant?

Comment: I think this question should be addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions